# What is the difference bewteen for loop and multily operation(*) in list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, operation

I have just got a question from a collegue, but I couldn't exlpain it well to him.
the problem is that the result of two operation was different.
example code is like this

`n,m = 10,10
d = [[0]* m for _ in range(n)]
f = [[ 0 ] * m] * n`

and the situation that I'm in a pickle is as follows.

```
d[0][1] = 1-> it sets only [0][1] to 1

f[0][1] = 1-> it sets all the elements in the column of index to 1
```

the results

```
d = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
f = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried bool(d==f), but the result was True.
I'm so confused of this difference.
please help me, please let me know why it is!
thank you for reading my question.

Comment: `[[0]* m for _ in range(n)]` this creates *n* lists of size *m* filled with zeros, `[[ 0 ] * m] * n` this creates a *n* references to the object `[ 0 ] * m]` so any change in one them is reflected in everyone of them.

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you for letting me know! I've resolved it with another stackoverflow page!